# Redirect from website.com to website.com/keyword1-keyword2/

Tags: seo, redirects, html

When a user visits my page through the URL **website.com**, I want it to be redirected to **website.com/keyword1-keyword2/**, as I have all the relevant information and SEO power in the index.html file of that directory (i.e. keywords in the directory name relevant for SEO).

I have written an index.html file for the root directory, and made a “Enter Website” button as a link target to the preferred directory. But is there a way I can circumvent this method? I’m aware of the <meta http-equiv="refresh" …> tag, but just wanted to know if there’s another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your post is very clear.  Is "keyword1-keyword2" a fixed string or does it depend on how they came to the website or what they posted/put in a form to get there?   What web server are you using and what framework?  There are LOTS of ways to handle redirects.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply. I want to put the keywords in the URL ("keyword1-keyword2"), so I made a directory in Hostinger's file manager with these keywords, as I read that it's good for SEO. I don't use any CMS and write the HTML/CSS myself.

Comment: Ask hostinger if they support .htaccess files - and if so, write some rewrite rules and add to .htaccess.   If they don't you may need to use a cdn to do that or consider changing from pure html/css to php + html + css and building a simple framework (eg on php).  I would do it using include files but you can also use a redirect header.